# Must the result be a convex function when a linear function multiple a convex function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

If $f(x)$ is a linear function,and $g(x)$ is a convex function,and $y(x)=f(x) \times g(x)$,must $y(x)$ still a convex function?assume $f(x)>0$, how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $g(x)$ is a convex function then $g(x)$ is a convex function.

I think you meant to ask if $y(x)$ is a convex function. If so, the answer is no, simply let $f(x)$ be the constant function equal to $-1$, and let $g(x)$ be any non-linear convex function, e.g. $g(x)=x^2$ on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: you need an example of $g$. you can't just say any $g$ (e.g. $g = 0$)

Comment: @mathworker21 fair (if pedantic) point, but as xkcd says the best kind of correctness is the "well, technically..." kind

Comment: $g = 1$ ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: +1 ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you for ensuring correctness of my answer

Comment: so if the value of f(x) is always positive,the answer will be yes?

Comment: @shineele: What is a linear function that is always positive?

Comment: @Rahul I mean ,like  $1-0.001 $ to $ 1-0.999$